# Plotting on a large number of facets

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to make a plot similar to the one that appears on the seaborn page: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/many_facets.html.

```
  index state_name     totalprod
0   28  North Dakota    475085000.0
1   3   California      347535000.0
2   34  South Dakota    266141000.0
3   5   Florida         247048000.0
4   21  Montana         156562000.0
```

To see the variation during the period in a graph initially, and then get the percentages. I'm trying the following,

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(df_bystate, col="state_name", palette="tab20c", col_wrap=4)
grid.map(plt.axhline, y=0, ls=":")
grid.map(plt.plot, [("year", "totalprod")], marker="o")
grid.set(xticks=np.arange(5), yticks=[-5, 5], xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(-5.5, 5.5))
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 3)
```

But the graphics are not generated with the data that supposed. I'm new to this and I do not know what I'm doing wrong, so I ask for your patience.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data: copy the data, paste it into the question, and format it as code. ...[You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: From [the docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html): the `data` argument is supposed to be - `Tidy ("long-form") dataframe where each column is a variable and each row is an observation.` does that sound like your data?

Comment: Yes it is. Each column represents a variable and the rows are observations

Comment: Line 3 refers to a column named "year" but it does not exist in the data provided.